# How to Bypass Output Cache in SharePoint 2007 Publishing Internet site

Tags: sharepoint, caching

We're building a mobile-friendly site to work in tandem with our client's MOSS 2007 internet site. We need to be able to redirect users who hit the home page and are using a mobile device.

Our original intention was to add a custom control to the home page page layout that would detect the current user's device and redirect to the mobile site accordingly. We quickly realised that this would not work as we are using the Output Caching functionality provided by SharePoint/Asp.Net. This means that the detection code will only run for the first visitor to the home page until the cache expires.

Our next idea was to build a custom HTTP Module and process the detection there. However, we are finding that the Output Caching is not allowing that either. If the cache is set while a mobile device is visiting all browsers are subsequently redirected to the mobile site (until the cache expires).

If we turn off output caching it works just fine - but we cannot turn output caching off, especically for the home page. We did investigate Substitution (Donut) Caching but this is not working due to the fact we are filtering the Asp.Net response within another HTTP Module that tidies up the rendered HTML for XHTML compatiblity reasons. I've also experimented with the output cache profile by setting it to vary-by-header property to "User-Agent" but I am getting mixed results and am also concerned at the memory implications of caching multipel versions of pages (we already have memory issues now and then).

It's possible we could run the redirection code in JavaScript but then we risk not detecting a lot of devices that don't have JavaScript enabled. This is a government website so the usage of JavaScript has to abide by accessibility guidelines.

Does anyone have any other ideas as to how we can solve this issue. Has anyone done this before? Perhaps in a different way?

Hope you can help, thanks.

p.s. I have also asked this [question on SharePoint.SE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/7692/950) but wanted to get as many eyes on this as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to try  [ISAPI filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting suggestion and would probably work. My skillset led me down a different path though and have provided an alternative approach below.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually solved this one I think. I've pretty much followed this article here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms550239.aspx. We have updated the code in that article to build a cache key based on whether the current page is the home page, whether the current user is using a mobile device and whether or not a cookie exists forcing the user to the full site. I will probably write this up as a blog post. When I do I will update this answer providing a link.